# Can you actually swing, shoot, throw while suspended in the air with a jetpack?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, flight

**Disclaimer: I don't know a single thing about aerodynamics but I'm hoping to get a little pointers in where to start.**

I'm currently writing a fantasy story where jetpacks are a very practical and efficient thing. I plan on having aerial combat and skirmishes of various different flavors (melee, ranged...etc) but I don't know the first thing about how aerodynamics work. So my questions are:

Could you possibly successfully swing a sword/polearm in the air? Could you also throw a javelin, pebbles? What about shooting a gun?

Yes or no, I would like to know the aerodynamic principles behind why not or why yes.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Is the question only about real jetpacks that just have nozzles pointing down to counteract gravity, or would you also want to consider hypothetical variant designs that would make combat easier, perhaps by having nozzles on the sides that are connected to accelerometers and try to provide a counter-force whenever you start to suddenly accelerate in some direction?

Comment: I am open to all ideas of every kind :) ! I'm more than interested in hearing what you have in mind. Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 11):

Swinging a sword, throwing a javelin or even shooting a gun isn't your problem while suspended in the air via a jetpack; doing damage with them and maintaining your balance on the other hand is. Basically, you're not just fighting your enemy up there, you're also fighting Isaac Newton.

To explain further, the damage a warrior does with a broadsword is partly through how he can wield it to deal damage, but also partly through his purchase on the ground. Newton's third law states that for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction so when the warrior strikes with the sword, there is actually momentum pushing him back as much as there is momentum pushing the sword forward. The difference is that the traction the warrior has on the ground absorbs that momentum meaning it takes more energy to stop the sword, meaning the strike is more powerful. This is a simplification but functionally correct. The point being, your swordsman will only get about half the energy of the strike in the air, the other half pushing him back slightly.

With the gun, it's the same thing; your bullets will not only push out with great speed, but they will also push you back because you have no traction with the ground.

This already happens in real life. One of the most iconic (IMO) surface attack planes in existence is the A-10 Warthog, with its GAU-8/a Avenger gun mounted at the front. That gun has so much power, that if pilots are not careful a sustained volley from the front facing cannon can actually slow the plane to the point where its engines stall. This is in turn part of the reason it has such powerful engines in the first place; to try to keep it in position as it's firing.

Your jetpackers will have a similar problem. They can fire guns, throw javelins and the like and still do damage, but because they have no purchase on the ground part of that energy goes into pushing them out of position.

As an aside, if you're shooting at the ground, this might actually aid your flight. Randall Monroe, as part of his What If series, has done a piece on using [machine guns as a jetpack](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/). That is probably a good starting point for some of the physics involved in the solution to your question.

EDIT: Thanks to E1E1, there is a weapon that a jetpacker may use effectively in the air; a Rocket Propelled Grenade, or RPG. These weapons are essentially hollow pipes that act as launch tubes for small explosive rockets, and most importantly they discharge their exhaust out the back. So, the momentum should be close to neutral for them, making them the ideal airborne weapon it would seem.

Comment: Unless you're using RPGs...

Comment: @ElEl true, that's a good point insofar as a recoiless weapon that discharges out the back will help solve the problem of momentum. RPGs are about the only weapon for which that works that I can think of, but even so you've got an instant rocket arena deathmatch in the works with that idea.

Comment: or if you have big rockets strapped on your back. But that isn't the safest idea... The fire will scorch you.

Comment: @TimBII and ElEl Can't thank you enough ! This is a very thorough and concise response which is very much appreaciated !!

Comment: @Anonymousworldbuilding Since regular guns will push you back, you could have your skirmishers actually take advantage of that to alter their momentum as they fight, using it to take tighter turns or come to a stop faster.

Answer (score 5):

In order to compensate for sudden pushes from weapon impacts or from swinging weapons or shooting, you might consider jetpacks with something similar to the [reaction control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_control_system) thrusters on many spacecraft, with nozzles that point in different directions from the main thruster (like smaller nozzles in different directions from the downward-pointing ones on the jetpack) which can be used to provide small impulses in any desired direction.

[image]

*Reaction control assemblies on the LEM (from [this page](https://dodlithr.blogspot.com/2012/07/lem-rcs-lunar-module-reaction-control.html))*

These could be coupled with an [accelerometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer) on the jetpack that detects sudden changes of velocity due to sources other than the thrusters, and tries to compensate to bring the user back to rest, or to whatever velocity they were moving before the change. There might also be more subtle computations that would be able to distinguish changes due to the user's own body movements that would feel "natural" if they were doing the same movements standing on the ground, and to avoid overcompensating for them. I found [this paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20130012773.pdf) for a proposal for a new type of [manned maneuvering unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Maneuvering_Unit) for space missions, which talks about how existing MMUs on EVA (extravehicular activity) missions sometimes overcompensate for body movements:

> This maneuvering unit has gas thrusters for attitude control and translation. When EVA astronauts are performing tasks that require fine motor control such as sample collection and equipment placement, the current control system will fire thrusters to compensate for the resulting changes in center-of-mass location and moments of inertia, adversely affecting task performance. The proposed design of a next-generation maneuvering and stability system incorporates control concepts optimized to support astronaut tasks and adds control-moment gyroscopes (CMGs) to the current Jetpack system. This design aims to reduce fuel consumption, as well as improve task performance for astronauts by providing a stiffer work platform.

And p. 14 talks about an example involving an astronaut using a hammer on an asteroid:

> The collection of samples from an asteroid’s surface using a drill or hammering device could impart reaction forces and torques onto the free-floating astronaut, resulting in undesired translating or tumbling. While both control modes would return the astronaut back to the initial reference attitude, the CMGs would provide a smoother response, providing a stiffer work platform so that tasks can be performed without the use of multiple anchor points. Reducing the number of attachment points can greatly increase the astronaut’s capability to work in unfamiliar areas, decreasing the amount of time needed to complete tasks.

So one could probably do something similar for swinging or firing weapons, especially if the jetpack has cameras that can follow the person's movements and those of nearby objects and predict what the forces on the person are going to be in the near future.

Comment: Underrated response right here ! Just wanted to  thank you for the insightful post, thanks a bunch !